# How to connect to a third party website in classic asp using javascript for password encryption and yet not giving in the password

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic, https

I have to make changes to classic asp website where once a button is clicked it autologins to a third party website with a intermediate page that warns that you are logging in to a third party website.

The thirdparty is providing us with a username and password and gave us an examle javascript to encode the password to send to them. Now where do I store the userid and password. I cannot execute the javascript on the serverside. It has to go to the client. If the asp page which has the encryption javascript goes to the client side then the source can be viewed and the username and password is given out.

Is there a way that I can have hidden asp page whose only job is to encrypt the password and create a new url and auto redirect it to that new url.

So when the user clicks ok on the intermediate warning page I redirect it to this hidden asp page which does the encryption and a creates a url for get method and redirects to that page.

I am a novice as far as java script and classic asp is concerned. Any ideas/ advice will be appreciated.

Thanks,

--Abbi

Comment: If the browser needs to send the password to the other server, it is fundamentally impossible to prevent the user from seeing it.

Comment: Can you suggest any other way to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Just wondering will it be a good idea ( using asp.net lingo as thats what i am used to ) to move the encryption code from java script to asp code.Then use something like server.transfer instead of response.redirect  to this encryption algorithm page and then get redirected to the newly created url.

Comment: I'm a little confused - are you sending the password **in plain text** to the third-party site, or are you sending an encrypted version of the password? You say in your question that you have been given "javascript to encode the password" - does that mean like base-64 encode it, or do you mean that it is encrypted in some fashion?

Comment: Thanks Scott for looking into it. Finally the problem got resolved. I changed the third part javascript code to vb script to run as asp page on the server and not on client. The asp page has inbuilt security to it so only logged in person will have access to the page.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks said, it really doesn't matter what you do, if the client browser MUST send the user/pass to the final website, then you cannot prevent that client browser from being able to see that user/pass.  It MUST see it, in order to provide it to the other website.

What you might want to consider is creating a page that is loaded server side and presented to the client browser from your website.  Think iframe (but not an iframe, that's still client side); where your server requests the page from the destination server, and then presents that page back to the browser.  This could get very complex depending on the kinds of interactions that happen on that page; you would basically need to proxy all GET's and POST's between your server and the destination site.  But this would eliminate the need for giving the browser the username and password.